# SQL query to find the entries corresponding to the maximum count of each type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table X in Postgres with the following entries

```
A     B     C
2     3     1
3     3     1
0     4     1
1     4     1
2     4     1
3     4     1
0     5     1
1     5     1
2     5     1
3     5     1
0     2     2
1     2     3
```

I would like to find out the entries having maximum of Column C for every kind of A and B i.e (group by B) with the most efficient query possible and return corresponding A and B.

Expected Output:

```
A     B      C
1     2      3
2     3      1
0     4      1    
0     5      1
```

Please help me with this problem . Thank you

Comment: In your example you do not have any doubles (A,B) rows. So every row is its own MAX.

Comment: You can't group by B only and have every kind of A with it.

Comment: For better testing, I recommend to add more different values for C. Because always 1 makes no sense for your use case

Comment: Why is A = 1 on B = 4. And not 0?

Comment: Yes 0 also works fine. I have edited

Comment: Changed solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5b96c012b24740c42fa86770a3a16919)

Using `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (B)
    A, B, C
FROM
    my_table
ORDER BY B, C DESC, A
```

`DISTINCT ON` gives you exactly the first row for an ordered group. In this case `B` is grouped.

After ordering `B` (which is necessary): We first order the maximum `C` (with `DESC`) to the top of each group. Then (if there are tied `MAX(C)` values) we order the `A` to get the minimum `A` to the top.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, I need the columns A,B for the maximum(C) grouped by the column B

Comment: If you want to group only B which value do you want to take for A? E.g. for group B = 4, the MAX(C) is 1 (because all is 1), which A should I take?

Comment: If the counts are same then first entry with that count can be considered or if there is a distinct maximum, then the corresponding entries must be considered. Thanks

Comment: Do you want COUNT or MAX?

Comment: I need MAX for this problem

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2ba60119ed0f3c08460563afdf65a91c is this what you want?

Comment: Can I get only the first element in each group after doing the partitioning?

Comment: What do you mean? The grouping/distinct always gives only one element... I recommend that you should add an expected output to the question to avoid long discussions :)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I will add the expected output now

Comment: Thank you so much, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it is a greatest n per group problem:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY C DESC, A ASC) AS rnk
    FROM t
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
```

You're not clear which `A` needs to be considered, the above returns the row with smallest `A`.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
   select * from (SELECT t.*,
   rank() OVER (PARTITION BY A,B order by C) rank 
   FROM tablename t)
   where rank=1 ;
```

Comment: I need the row in A and B for corresponding max(C) group by B. Could you please help with that

Answer (score 0):

itseems to me you need max()

```
select A,B, max(c) from table_name
group by A,B
```